# Mongodb regex assistance

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am learning python with mongodb.

My input data is:

```
{'Period': '12-2015',
 'data': [{'EndDate': '10-12-2015',
           'Pid': '566bb17761be0b1e0059c09d',
           'Registration': 'TN 64 KS 7777',
           'StartDate': '5-12-2015',
           'Status': 'Booked'},
          {'EndDate': '20-12-2015',
           'Pid': '566bb17761be0b1e0059c09d',
           'Registration': 'TN 64 KS 7777',
           'StartDate': '15-12-2015',
           'Status': 'NA'},
          {'EndDate': '24-12-2015',
           'Pid': '566bb17761be0b1e0059c09d',
           'Registration': 'TN 64 KS 7777',
           'StartDate': '21-12-2015',
           'Status': 'AOs'},
          {'EndDate': '30-12-2015',
           'Pid': '566bb17761be0b1e0059c09d',
           'Registration': 'TN 64 KS 7777',
           'StartDate': '25-12-2015',
           'Status': 'AOr'}]}
```

I am trying to update the table like this:

```
for values in data:
    yield db.calender.update({"StartDate": values['StartDate']}, values)
```

I also tried

```
for values in data:
    yield db.calender.update({"StartDate": values['StartDate']}, 
                             {"StartDate": values['StartDate'],
                              "EndDate": values['EndDate'],
                              "Status": values['Status'],
                              "Registration": values['Registration'],
                              "Pid": values['Pid']})
```

based on this documentation [from mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.update/#example-update-replace-fields)

but the data was not updated in the calendar table.

Comment: What is `data`? is it your input data?, can you show sample document from the `calendar`  collection?

Comment: yes.calendar collection is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the `update` method because your collection is empty unless you set `upsert` to `True` but  this still doesn't make any sense . You need to use the [`insert_many`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_many) method.

```
input_data = {'Period': '12-2015',
 'data': [{'EndDate': '10-12-2015',
           'Pid': '566bb17761be0b1e0059c09d',
           'Registration': 'TN 64 KS 7777',
           'StartDate': '5-12-2015',
           'Status': 'Booked'},
          {'EndDate': '20-12-2015',
           'Pid': '566bb17761be0b1e0059c09d',
           'Registration': 'TN 64 KS 7777',
           'StartDate': '15-12-2015',
           'Status': 'NA'},
          {'EndDate': '24-12-2015',
           'Pid': '566bb17761be0b1e0059c09d',
           'Registration': 'TN 64 KS 7777',
           'StartDate': '21-12-2015',
           'Status': 'AOs'},
          {'EndDate': '30-12-2015',
           'Pid': '566bb17761be0b1e0059c09d',
           'Registration': 'TN 64 KS 7777',
           'StartDate': '25-12-2015',
           'Status': 'AOr'}]}

data = input_data['data']
yield db.calender.insert_many(data)
```

As you can see you don't need to iterate over the element in the "data" array.